# The expression is not supported error when accessing Azure Tables

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to get some records from the Azure Table Storage while using paging with the continuation token.

I have the following code:

```
public Stories SelectStory(DateTime start, DateTime end, string searchGuid)
{
  long startTicks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - start.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;
  long endTicks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - end.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;

  var stories = _ServiceContext.CreateQuery<Story>("Story").Where(s => Convert.ToInt64(s.RowKey.Substring(0, s.PartitionKey.IndexOf("_"))) > startTicks
         && Convert.ToInt64(s.RowKey.Substring(0, s.PartitionKey.IndexOf("_"))) < endTicks
         && s.RowKey == "story_" + searchGuid).Take(50);
  var query = stories as DataServiceQuery<Story>;
  var results = query.Execute();
  var response = results as QueryOperationResponse;

  Stories temp = new Stories();
  if(response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey"))
  {
    temp.NextPartitionKey = response.Headers["x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey"];
    if (response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey"))
    {
      temp.NextRowKey = response.Headers["x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey"];
    }
  }
  temp.List = results.ToList();

  return temp;
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
 The expression (((ToInt64([10007].RowKey.Substring(0, [10007].PartitionKey.IndexOf("_"))) > 2521167043199999999) And (ToInt64([10007].RowKey.Substring(0, [10007].PartitionKey.IndexOf("_"))) < 2521154083199999999)) And ([10007].RowKey == "story_9")) is not supported.
```

I'm not sure why the expression is not allowed. Does anyone have any ideas how I can change it to get it to work?

Thanks!

Edit: the new code (no errors but no data gets selected - even though i know it exists):

```
public Stories SelectStory(DateTime start, DateTime end, string searchGuid)
    {
        long startTicks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - start.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;
        long endTicks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - end.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;

        var strStart = string.Format("{0:10}_{1}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - startTicks, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");
        var strEnd = string.Format("{0:10}_{1}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - endTicks, "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000");

        var stories = _ServiceContext.CreateQuery<Story>("Story").Where(
                        s => s.RowKey.CompareTo(strStart) < 0
                            && s.RowKey.CompareTo(strEnd) > 0
                           //s.RowKey.CompareTo(startTicks.ToString() + "_") > 0
                     //&& s.RowKey.CompareTo(endTicks.ToString() + "_00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") > 0
                     && s.PartitionKey == ("story_" + searchGuid)
                     ).Take(50);
        var query = stories as DataServiceQuery<Story>;
        var results = query.Execute();
        var response = results as QueryOperationResponse;

        Stories temp = new Stories();
        if(response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey"))
        {
            temp.NextPartitionKey = response.Headers["x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey"];
            if (response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey"))
            {
                temp.NextRowKey = response.Headers["x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey"];
            }
        }
        temp.List = results.ToList();

        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think there are a couple of things going on here.  One I think there is a logic flaw.  Shouldn't

```
Convert.ToInt64(s.RowKey.Substring(0, s.PartitionKey.IndexOf("_")))
```

be

```
Convert.ToInt64(s.PartitionKey.Substring(0, s.PartitionKey.IndexOf("_")))
```

Secondly you need to be very careful about which functions are supported by azure table queries.  Generally they're not.  I've tested `.Substring()` and `.IndexOf()` and they don't work in Azure Table queries, so the chances of `.ToInt64()` working is slim to none.

You might be able to reformat this to be

```
s => s.PartitionKey > startTicks.ToString() + "_"
&& s.PartitionKey < endTicks.ToString() + "_"
&& s.RowKey == "story_" + searchGuid
```

This will likely not generate a very efficient query because Azure can get confused if you have two filters based on partition key and just do a table scan.  Another option is to not include the endTicks part of the query and when you process the results, when you get to one the partition key is greater than end ticks, stop processing the results.

Also your code as you have it written won't get all of the items based on the continuation token, it will just get the first set of results that are returned.  I think your final code should look something like this (uncompiled, untested and I'm sure people can see some performance improvements:

```
private class ListRowsContinuationToken
{
    public string NextPartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string NextRowKey { get; set; }
}

public Stories SelectStory(DateTime start, DateTime end, string searchGuid)
{
    long startTicks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - start.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;
    long endTicks = DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - end.ToUniversalTime().Ticks;

var stories = _ServiceContext.CreateQuery<Story>("Story").Where(s => s.PartitionKey > startTicks.ToString() + "_"
                && s.PartitionKey < endTicks.ToString() + "_"
                && s.RowKey == "story_" + searchGuid).Take(50);

var query = stories as DataServiceQuery<Story>;

Stories finalList = new Stories();

var results = query.Execute();

ListRowsContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
bool reachedEnd = false;

do
{
    if ((continuationToken != null))
    {
        servicesQuery = servicesQuery.AddQueryOption("NextPartitionKey", continuationToken.NextPartitionKey);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationToken.NextRowKey))
        {
            servicesQuery.AddQueryOption("NextRowKey", continuationToken.NextRowKey);
        }
    }

    var response = (QueryOperationResponse<T>)query.Execute();

    foreach (Story result in response)
    {
        if (result.PartitionKey < endTicks.ToString())
        {
            finalList.AddRange(result);
        }
        else
        {
            reachedEnd = true;
        }
    }

    if (response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey"))
    {
        continuationToken = new ListRowsContinuationToken
        {
            NextPartitionKey = response.Headers["x-ms-continuation-NextPartitionKey"]
        };

        if (response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey"))
        {
            continuationToken.NextRowKey = response.Headers["x-ms-continuation-NextRowKey"];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        continuationToken = null;
    }

} while (continuationToken != null && reachedEnd == false);

return finalList;
```

}

Comment: You're right there was a logical error, but it should have been: Convert.ToInt64(s.RowKey.Substring(0, s.RowKey.IndexOf("_")))

You're also right about the continuation token, if I'm only taking some results then there obviously won't be a continuation token. 

I'm going to try fixing it right now and see if it works. Thanks for the help!  Really appreciate a response - I've spent all day on this.

Comment: I believe partition ranges (like x < pk && pk < y) are actually efficient, so I don't think you need to worry about that.  However, I believe the less than and greater than operations will need to be replaced with PartitionKey.CompareTo(...) < 0 and PartitionKey.CompareTo(...) > 0.

Comment: I keep hearing conflicting messages about what you can and can't use in a query that references partition keys (talk of possible table scans scares the hell out of me).  Maybe someone should produce a canonical reference and put it in video somewhere...It seems it's purely academic in this case as it's meant to be row key anyway.

Comment: I'm curious as to how the RowKey can be {numberofticks}_{something else} and also story_{a guid}?

Comment: The RowKey is {max ticks - ticks of data}_{guid} and the partition key is story_{guid}. I've also updated the post to reflect what I tried. @smarx you are correct, I had to use CompareTo as < > wasn't allowed. But it's still not working - no elements are being selected.

Comment: I just updated the post showing the new code (with compare to) - although there is still a problem. The selected list is empty.

Comment: I'd be trying a process of elimination here.  Try with just the partition key filter, then add bits in.  See at what point it stops working.  Using LinqPad may make this quicker after you set it up. http://geekswithblogs.net/IUnknown/archive/2010/03/10/linqpad-with-azure-table-storage.aspx

Comment: @rksprst I think your CompareTo's are backwards.  (You're currently querying for something LESS than start and GREATER than end.  You want the opposite.  Also, I bet you want greater than OR EQUAL TO the start.)